# Android: Opening files from OneDrive gives FileNotFound EACCESS Permission Denied error

Tags: android, onedrive

Got a user trying to open files from my app via the [OneDrive app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.skydrive&hl=en). Everything seems to throw "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

OneDrive v4.4 on Android 4.1 and 4.4 if that helps.

To start the activity:

```
chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooseFile.setType("*/*");
chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file"), ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
```

In onActivityResult():

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();

// Works for every other "file explorer" or source (dropbox, google drive, etc)
try {
    info.stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
}
// OneDrive always ends up at this error case
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return info;
}
```

Also added these permissions for testing sake but no luck.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

I've done another test and realised that not even Chrome can read files from OnePath when trying to upload via web forms.

However, [QuickEdit Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.edit) can read files from OneDrive but it seems to need root access.

Any ideas on how to do this?

edit: Stack-trace as requested

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.microsoft.skydrive/no_backup/stream_cache/X@gmail.com/8/$R1N6ZQC.xml: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:447)
W/System.err:     at codepeekercommon.CodePeekerBaseActivity.getFileInfoFromIntent(CodePeekerBaseActivity.java:533)
W/System.err:     at codepeekercommon.CodePeekerBaseActivity$5.run(CodePeekerBaseActivity.java:424)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
W/System.err:   ... 14 more
```

Comment: You might wish to post the code for your `startActivityForResult()` that is triggering the code you show above, along with the full stack trace. I doubt that it will help -- this feels specific to OneDrive -- but you never know...

Comment: Post edited. Thanks for the suggestions Mark.

Comment: I have same problem here. Have you still the error ?

Comment: Yes. I added a message to my users when they tried to select something from OneDrive saying the app returns invalid data. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34156464/253704 for more info

Answer (score 2):

Based off of that stack trace, OneDrive is handing back a `file:` `Uri`, pointing to a location on internal storage for their app.

There's nothing that you can do, short of root, to access that content. Hopefully, one day, Microsoft will fix OneDrive, such that it returns something else (e.g., a `content:` `Uri`, where they use `FileProvider` or roll their own).

Comment: Thought as much. When QuickEdit Text Editor requested root access to view that content I figured it wasn't an ordinary workaround. Thanks for the confirmation.